# running cassandra image into the new version 3.0 starter openshift

Tags: docker, cassandra, kubernetes, openshift

when trying to run a cassandra image into a openshift (new version 3.0 starter) when trying to run the docker image it wont load due to this...
"Image cassandra runs as the root user which might not be permitted by your cluster administrator."
ANY ONE CAN HELP ME? i'm trying to dealing with this for a time
i'm trying to do so using this: https://github.com/keedio/openshift-cassandra

Comment: What is the actual error in the pod logs if it is failing? Also, if that error is showing, it suggests that you aren't deploying the image built from that repository, as the ``Dockerfile`` is closed out as non ``root`` user. Provide more details on what steps you have run to try and deploy that repo.

Comment: Like @GrahamDumpleton's suggestion I think the issue you are hitting is because your trying to pull an image that tries to run as a root user.

Please see https://docs.openshift.com/online/creating_images/guidelines.html#openshift-specific-guidelines for information on why we don't allow this.

Comment: i just go to the dashboard-> DEPLOY IMAGE...
here are the images:


https://ibb.co/fpYBKx


https://ibb.co/jRnGmc


https://ibb.co/gvD0CH

Comment: ok, but how can i do to do so? are there any way i can bring up a cassandra/docker installing in red had openshift that would be free only for testing purpose?

Comment: @christian130 You need to click on 'View log' to see what the error messages from the pod is. The message about root is a warning only and not an indication of what the problem is.

Comment: Running Cassandra as root user or group is not recommended - please start Cassandra using a different system user.
If you really want to force running Cassandra as root, use -R command line option. 



https://ibb.co/kgbLUx

Comment: The problem then is the check they have for running as ``root`` user or ``root`` group. In the case of OpenShift, it isn't running as ``root`` user, but because the assigned user ID does not have an entry in the ``/etc/passwd`` file, it defaults to using ``root`` group. This is perfectly fine in a containerised environment and there is no risk from running as group ``root``. They are being overly cautious. You will need to supply that ``-R`` option somehow to force it to get past that check.

Comment: Can you post about it on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/openshift and we can follow up there.

Comment: I'm finding it hard to follow what your doing, as the git repo your using has a docker image that uses -R when starting Cassandra. What image are you using?